# Can Converter @FacesConverter(forClass=[someClass.class]) be implemented as @Singleton @Lock(READ)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, converters, openejb, apache-tomee

In an effort to remove 'static' declarations throughout my app (to help JVM's GC), I removed 'static' from the definition of the Converter class below. So that resulted in the infamous error below:

```
Apr 13, 2013 4:10:38 AM org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl internalCreateConverter
SEVERE: Could not instantiate converter jsf.CustomerController$CustomerControllerConverter
java.lang.InstantiationException: jsf.CustomerController$CustomerControllerConverter
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.internalCreateConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1626)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1545)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.createConverter(ApplicationWrapper.java:158)
```

I assume 'static' is necessary, because only one copy of the class is created per application. Correct? So, can I define the class as a @Singleton @Lock(READ) to resolve the issue?

Per NetBeans generated JSF controller/bean code, the Converter is usually defined in the same .java file as the controller or @ManagedBean. Honestly, I do 'not' want to use addConverter() or converterId="..." in the xhtml. I prefer to use @FacesConverter, since this has been working for me throughout the app.

```
package jsf;

import jpa.entities.Customer;
import jpa.session.CustomerFacade;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@ManagedBean(name = "customerController")
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private jpa.session.CustomerFacade ejbFacade;

    public CustomerController() {
    }

    @FacesConverter(forClass = Customer.class)
    public class CustomerControllerConverter implements Converter {

        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            /*
             * 2012-07-10 when user enters invalid/incomplete value (e.g. "irene", see below) in AutoComplete
             *
            WARNING: For input string: "irene"
            java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "irene"
                    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
                    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
                    at jsf.pointOfContact.pf_PointOfContactController$PointOfContactControllerConverter.getKey(pf_PointOfContactController.java:1625)
                    at jsf.pointOfContact.pf_PointOfContactController$PointOfContactControllerConverter.getAsObject(pf_PointOfContactController.java:1620)
                    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.getConvertedValue(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:529)
                    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
                    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
             *
             */
            try {
                Integer test = getKey(value);
            } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }
            CustomerController controller = (CustomerController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                    getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "customerController");
            return controller.ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
        }

        java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
            java.lang.Integer key;
            key = Integer.valueOf(value);
            return key;
        }

        String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append(value);
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (object instanceof Customer) {
                Customer o = (Customer) object;
                return getStringKey(o.getCustomerId());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + Customer.class.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise.

ALSO, please let me know how to get email notifications whenever someone responds to my questions here on stackoverflow.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES, with a little help from JNDI lookup.

I just removed the CustomerControllerConverter from the JSF @RequestScoped CustomerController, created the converter class, marked it with @Singleton @Lock(READ), and referenced the @Stateless EJB via JNDI lookup. See below.

```
package converter;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.ejb.AccessTimeout;
import javax.ejb.Lock;
import javax.ejb.LockType;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import jpa.entities.Customer;
import jpa.session.CustomerFacade;


/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
@AccessTimeout(value = 1, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
@FacesConverter(forClass = Customer.class)
public class CustomerConverter implements Converter {

    public CustomerConverter() {

    }

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        /*
         * 2012-07-10 when user enters invalid/incomplete value (e.g. "irene", see below) in AutoComplete
         *
        WARNING: For input string: "irene"
        java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "irene"
                at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
                at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
                ...
                ...
                at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.getConvertedValue(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:529)
                at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
                at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
         *
         */
        try {
            Integer test = getKey(value);
        } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
        }
        Object object = null;
        CustomerFacade ejbFacade;
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            ejbFacade = (CustomerFacade) ic.lookup("java:global/appWARFileNameOrAppContextName/CustomerFacade");
            if (ejbFacade == null) {
                System.err.println("CustomerConverter.getAsObject(): ejbFacade = null)");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("CustomerConverter.getAsObject(): error on JNDI lookup of CustomerFacade");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        try {
            object = ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("CustomerConverter.getAsObject(): error on ejbFacade.find(getKey(value))");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return object;
    }

    java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
        java.lang.Integer key;
        key = Integer.valueOf(value);
        return key;
    }

    String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(value);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (object instanceof Customer) {
            Customer o = (Customer) object;
            return getStringKey(o.getCustomerId());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + Customer.class.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

LESSON LEARNED: ejbFacade could NOT be referenced or instantiated via the following:

@Inject,
@EJB,
BeanManager

References:

Oracle blogs

1. [Ken Saks's Blog: Application-specified Portable JNDI Names](https://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/application_specified_portable_jndi_names)
2. [Ken Saks's Blog: Portable Global JNDI Names](https://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/portable_global_jndi_names)

TomEE JavaEE Examples - Referencing EJBs

1. [Injection Of Ejbs](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-ejbs/README.html)
2. [Lookup Of Ejbs with Descriptor](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/lookup-of-ejbs-with-descriptor/README.html)
3. [Lookup Of Ejbs](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/lookup-of-ejbs/README.html)

Ultimately, I had to refer to the server.log file of Glassfish, the Reference Implementation (RI), to see a sample of JNDI lookup path for my @Stateless EJB's, since I used Glassfish, in the past. :)

**UPDATE:**

You can also find the portable global JNDI name in TomEE/catalina log. It will look like this, below.

```
Apr 13, 2013 10:00:58 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=CustomerFacadeLocalBean) --> Ejb(deployment-id=CustomerFacade)

Apr 13, 2013 10:00:58 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/webApp/CustomerFacade!jpa.session.CustomerFacade) --> Ejb(deployment-id=CustomerFacade)

Apr 13, 2013 10:00:58 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/webApp/CustomerFacade) --> Ejb(deployment-id=CustomerFacade)
```

where 'webApp' in the global JNDI name may be the name of your WAR filename or possibly EJB JAR filename, etc...

Hope this helps others!